# How to recreate something similar to the way twitter shows its loading pages (the bird-to-spinner)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter, loading

How can I recreate the way that twitter loads in its webpages as shown in the image below 
I do understand that this could be achived by jQuery but I can't seem to find a good example because I want it to look seamless and not to make my websites UI messy.

Image 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3QYJ.png (Normal State)

Image 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmBYt.png (Loading State)

Answer (score 0):

The basics would be to load up both images, overlapping.  Set one to not be visible.  Then, using jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#loading").hide();
 $("#loaded").show();
});
```

Where `loaded` and `loading` are the id's of your images.